# Confirm Deletion Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, php, dialog, box

I have the following line of code

```
$product_list="$product_list $id - $product_name - $date_added       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a       href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br/>"
```

and

```
  if(isset($_GET['deleteid']))
  {
  echo 'Do you really want to delete this item with ID of '.$_GET['deleteid']. '? <a href = "inventory_list.php?yesdelete='.$_GET['deleteid']. '"> Yes</a> | <a href="inventory_list.php"> No</a>'; 
  exit();
}
```

How can I make it appear as a dialog box and do you think using a dialog box instead of going to the confirmation page will be a good option?

UPDATE

I tried the following but when ever deleteid gets set it creates another new delete link how can I make the existing delete link show the confirm box?

```
if(isset($_GET['deleteid']))
{
echo '<a href="inventory_list.php?yesdelete='.$_GET['deleteid']. '" onClick="return confirm(\'Do you want to delete?\');">Delete</a>';
}
```

UPDATED try

```
$product_list="$product_list $id - $product_name - $date_added   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a   href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$_GET[deleteid]' onClick='return confirm(\'Do    you want to delete?\');'>Delete</a><br/>"
```

Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I would use javascript for the Dialog box, either with an' extension such as bootstrap or perhaps just a simple confirm('') in JS. Whether it's a good option is 100% opinion based and should be decided on by you.

Comment: a little help with java script would be appreciated, i'm new to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var el = document.getElementById('deleteLink');
el.onclick = reallyDelete();    

function reallyDelete(){
   var verifyDelete = confirm("Really wanna delete?");

   if (verifyDelete == false) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
}
</script>
```

Then you'd of course have to add the ID (deleteLink) to the A link, and this will also only work if there is one link to "delete" otherwise you might need to use onClick, but I would recommend googling around for a tutorial on how to achieve the best solution for you.

(There is also still Bootstrap)

**UPDATE**

Replace

```
<a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a>
```

with

```
<a href="inventory_list.php?yesdelete='.$id. '" onClick="return confirm(\'Do you want to delete?\');">Delete</a>
```

And delete this:

```
if(isset($_GET['deleteid']))
{
    echo '<a href="inventory_list.php?yesdelete='.$_GET['deleteid']. '" onClick="return confirm(\'Do you want to delete?\');">Delete</a>';
}
```

Comment: Please see the updated question where I attempted your suggestion

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, it generates a new link? You just need to add id="deleteLink" to your existing link

Comment: please see the updated question with an attempt I tried.

Comment: please see the updated question with an attempt I tried.

Comment: Wrong link, you gotta put the ID in the link with <a       href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'

Comment: it does get deleted but like i said as soon as i click on the delete link a new delete link is made and when I click that then the dialog box appears.      https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/pi9nsioVpvh/nh1vMOhNxmp3FppP

Comment: it's because of what you have wrapped the code in, replace onClick='<code>' with onClick=\"<code>\"

Comment: the dialog box appears but after confirming nothing gets deleted  $product_list="$product_list $id - $product_name - $date_added &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$_GET[deleteid]' onClick=\"return confirm('Do you want to delete?')\";>delete</a><br/>"

Comment: That's because you are still using the wrong parameters for the URL, you are using ?deleteid=$id where you should use ?yesdelete=$id (remember to change the $_GET['id'] to $id